# Firebase: Flutter signInWithFacebook isn't defined for the class FirebaseAuth

Tags: facebook, firebase, flutter

### pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.5.0
flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0
```

### MainPage.dart

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
bool isLogged = false;
FirebaseUser myUser;

Future<FirebaseUser> _loginWithFacebook() async {
  var facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
  var result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
  debugPrint(result.status.toString());
  if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
    FirebaseUser user =
    await _auth.signInWithFacebook(accessToken: result.accessToken.token);
    return user;
  }
  return null;
}
```

### Error

> **`signInWithFacebook` isn't defined for the class `FirebaseAuth`**

Answer (score 1):

The method `FirebaseAuth.signInWithFacebook` was removed in version `0.7.0`. The updated approach is to use `FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential`.

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
bool isLogged = false;
FirebaseUser myUser;

Future<FirebaseUser> _loginWithFacebook() async {
  var facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
  var result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
  debugPrint(result.status.toString());
  if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
    FacebookAccessToken myToken = result.accessToken;
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: myToken.token);
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    return user;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i never used Facebook login with firebase just google sign, try it out let me know if it helped

```
if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
  FirebaseUser user =
  await _auth.signInWithCustomToken(accessToken: result.accessToken.token);
  return user;
```